# how can i get total of two numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

I'm using this form script to automatically calculate totals. Now I need to get that total and print it.
Here is my code.

```js
function myFunction()
  {
   var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
   var txt1 =x.elements[0].value;
   var txt2 =x.elements[1].value;
   var total =txt1+txt2;
     
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="total is :"+total;
  }
```

```html
<body>

 <form id="frm1">
   First value : <input type="text" name="first"><br>
   Second Value : <input type="text" name="second"><br>
   
 </form> 

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()"> ADD </button>

</body>
```

Comment: another high quality question.

Comment: Idd, @anbinfayas please provide more info next time - why doesn't it work (what does it do, and what should it do in detail) - whether an error is shown (if so, then on what line) etc... And I recommend gouing through some JavaScript tutorials to understand the basics ;)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really say, but I'm guessing you're talking about numbers, if so parse the string values as numbers before you add them up

```
function myFunction() {
    var x     = document.getElementById("frm1");
    var txt1  = parseFloat( x.elements[0].value );
    var txt2  = parseFloat( x.elements[1].value );
    var total = txt1 + txt2;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "total is :"+total;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9RnD/)